# Set Printer PageLayout margin to zero

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I created a small Javafx application that allows the user to print a node. I want the margin to be zero. I used the following code below, but it didn't work.

```
printer = javafx.print.Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.JAPANESE_POSTCARD,  PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

According to the documentation, the last four parameters in `createPageLayout` is the margins(Left,Right,Top,Bottom). I made a print-test but there still a `0.5 inch margin` in the printed document.

What's going on? Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a `hardware limitation issue` i.e. the margin that can be applied to a Paper depends on the hardware / printer and not just the `API` used to access it. In this case, though JavaFX allows you to pass margin values as `0`, but they are later re-assigned to support the printers minimum values.

From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/Printer.html#createPageLayout-javafx.print.Paper-javafx.print.PageOrientation-double-double-double-double-) :

> A client that needs to know what margin values are legal should first obtain a PageLayout using the HARDWARE_MINIMUM margins.
>
> If the printer cannot support the layout as specified, it will adjust the returned layout to a supported configuration

You can use [`Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/Printer.MarginType.html#HARDWARE_MINIMUM) while creating a layout, to check the minimum margin allowed.

```
pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.JAPANESE_POSTCARD,  
             PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the getPrintableWidth() and getPrintableHeight() methods to check what the actual margins are. Even though you set a 0 margin in the constructor, the hardware may limit the margins to a default size.